# MongoDB optimization

Tags: mongodb

I need to optimize my MongoDB performance but can't figure out how. Maybe there's some tips. Or maybe i should use another storage engine. Any ideas are welcome.

I have following log output in which are described query:

```
2015-08-04T15:09:56.226+0300 [conn129682] command mongodb_db1.$cmd command: aggregate { aggregate: "collection", pipeline: [ { $match: { _id.index_id_1: 4931359 } } ] } keyUpdates:0 numYields:39 locks(micros) r:83489 reslen:177280 286ms
```

I have collection named *collection* which contains following data structure:

```
{
  "_id" : {
    "x" : "x",
    "index_id_1" : NumberLong(5617088)
  },
  "value" : {
    "value_1" : 1.0000000000000000,
    "value_2" : 0.0000000000000000,
    "value_3" : 1.0000000000000000
  }
}
```

By querying stats in result i have following details:

```
 {
  "ns" : "mongodb_db1.collection",
  "count" : 2.07e+007,
  "size" : 4968000000.0000000000000000,
  "avgObjSize" : 240,
  "storageSize" : 5524459408.0000000000000000,
  "numExtents" : 25,
  "nindexes" : 3,
  "lastExtentSize" : 5.36601e+008,
  "paddingFactor" : 1.0000000000000000,
  "systemFlags" : 0,
  "userFlags" : 1,
  "totalIndexSize" : 4475975728.0000000000000000,
  "indexSizes" : {
    "_id_" : 2884043120.0000000000000000,
    "_id.x.index_id_1" : 1.07118e+009,
    "_id.index_id_1" : 5.20754e+008
  },
  "ok" : 1.0000000000000000
}
```

- Running on single node ( no shards ).
- MongoDB version is: 2.4.
- Installed RAM (MB): 24017 ( index size ~120GB )

Comment: Indexes. Query log anaysis. The list goes on. Love to answer, but it seems more like a series of articles than a definative answer to me.Database query optimisation is not exactly a "new topic". Even if it does not "seem" at first to apply to your brand new shiny NoSQL ( old enough to have used databases before SQL was even spoke of ) solution, it probably actualy "does suit really well". If you take the time to interpret such articles, ( and practice the principles) then they will serve you very well. The wheel has existed for millennia. Time to stop re-inventing it. "Way too-broad"

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I see and understand that there's no definitely single answer for this question and there's many things who can impact performance. I have registered in one of  @arober11 provided  courses and i hope that would help me out.

Answer (score 1):

10Gen / Mongodb are running a series of [FREE online courses](https://university.mongodb.com/courses), that cover all you need to know (Latest iteration starts today). Simply head over and sign up for the DBA course, and if your feeling brave a couple of the others, but there is a lot of common / duplicated material, between all variants at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks for link! I have registered in one of these courses and i hope that would help me out.